# how to set that only admin gete mail confirmation in magento

Tags: magento

I have a problem in magento.how to set that only admin get confirmation email after a cutomer purchase for example if a customer purchase a product and he does't want a confirmation email and unchecked the email confirmation option then I want admin get email.please help me in step by step

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension [disable mail](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-email-notifications.html)  for disable mail system for customer when customer place order.

You need create extension and create method for send mail to admin with this event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

When customer place order admin will get mail.